# «A quoi l'accord de Paris peut-il servir?» or «À quoi l'accord de Paris peut-il servir?»

Tags: diacritiques, majuscules

It's not the first time that I see this. At the beginning of a question, when I usually would expect to see an «à», I see an «a». Is this correct? In which situations am I allowed to this replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the age of typewriters, accents on capital letters couldn't be typed, so traditionally they were left off. Now they are optional, though many French speakers - and the [Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#5_strong-em-accentuation-des-majuscules-em-strong) - recommend using them.

> On veille donc, en bonne typographie, à utiliser systématiquement les capitales accentuées, y compris la préposition À